# Module machine type and target machine type Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am running a project with platform WIN32 but my laptop is 64bit. So if I choose the target machine type x64 it will announce : 
error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine 'x64' File opencv_ts300.lib
Then when I change the target machine type X86 it will announce
error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine 'X86' File Assemblyinfo.obj.
So what should I do? Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample so other people can try to reproduce and help you

Answer (score 1):

Your solution configuration isn't correct. Looks like you mismatched builds in VS "Configuration Manager". Also, it looks like your opencv_ts300.lib is built for x64, so if you don't have x86 built of opencv then you'll have to switch all your projects to x64 as well.

Comment: Oh yes, I edited the second error. Could you show me how to switch them to x64? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use inline assembly in Visual Studio x64 mode. The assemblyfile.obj is most likely written for x64 anf can't be linked to a x86-compiled c program thereby, causing the second error.

Comment: Yes, I tried to delete the assembly.obj but it didn't work. So what can I do to fix the error? thank you